# webpack is watching for changes node_modules/micromatch/index.js:44

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browser-sync

i am facing this error .I have deleted node_modules file many time still facing this problem
please help in reolving this problem

```
    let isMatch = picomatch(String(patterns[i]), { ...options, onResult }, true);
                                                   ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jayant/repo/jj/node_modules/browser-sync/dist/public/stream.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
[23:28:54] webpack is watching for changes
```

my node vesion is **v6.11.2** and npm version:**3.10.10**

Comment: Node v6 does not support the spread operator `...options` well at least for Objects, it should support it with arrays. You need newer version of Node.js, i believe it's supported since version 8.3

Comment: i have upgraded node to version 10 stll facing this erorr

Comment: What exact version do you have? See this to check if it supports it https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-object_rest/spread_properties

Comment: earlier i had v6.11.2 and now i having v10.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to upgrade my node version,upgrading could have solved my problem easily.
**I have resolve this issue by downgrading my browser-sync version i.e 2.26.7**
You can try installing every version of it , by `npm install browser-sync@version`

you can check version from https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync